# \end{enumerate} error

Tags: errors, enumerate

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{}{15}\selectfont}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\author{TEXT}
\title{TEXT}

\maketitle
    \section*{TEXT}
\begin{enumerate}[{1.}1]
    \item \textbf{TEXT}
    \begin{enumerate}[{1.1.}1]
        \item TEXT
        \item TEXT
        \item TEXT
        \item TEXT
        \begin{itemize}
            \item TEXT
            \item TEXT
            \item TEXT
        \end{itemize}
        \item TEXT
    \end{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{TEXT}
                \begin{enumerate}[{1.2.}1]
                    \item TEXT
                \end{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{TEXT}
                \begin{enumerate}[{1.3.}1]
                    \item TEXT
                \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Hi I have this text writen but TeXstudio Gives me the following errors:

```
- Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate} OR
- Missing number, treated as zero. \end{enumerate} for the lines with the \end{enumerate} code
- Package sectsty Error: The sectsty package doesn't work with(sectsty) this document class. scrartcl, scrbook, and scrreprt.}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't load both `enumitem` and `enumerate`. You're using the syntax of the latter, so remove `\usepackage{enumitem}`. However, this package is much more powerful, so you may want to switch.

Comment: Also, package `sectsty` throws a pretty clear error.

Comment: @Johannes_B Well, `extarticle` is based on `article`, so `sectsty` ought to work. But loading it alongside with `titlesec` is not a good idea either.

Comment: @egreg Yes, still, the error is annoying ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't mix the use of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) since their interfaces differ and are conflicting.

Perhaps you're after this type of layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm}
\begin{document}

\section{TEXT}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection.\arabic*]
  \item \textbf{TEXT}
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item TEXT
    \item TEXT
    \item TEXT
    \item TEXT
    \begin{itemize}
      \item TEXT
      \item TEXT
      \item TEXT
    \end{itemize}
    \item TEXT
  \end{enumerate}
  \item \textbf{TEXT}
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item TEXT
  \end{enumerate}
  \item \textbf{TEXT}
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item TEXT
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `label*` key uses the higher level `label` as part of its label.